# What type of lizard is this grey and orange one I found near the Grand Canyon?

Tags: united-states, animal-identification

While hiking to see the Grand Canyon on the North side, I found this grey and orange lizard running through some downed brush and logs (center of picture).

[image]

Would anyone know what type of lizard this is?

Answer (score 5):

That's definitely a [desert horned lizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desert_horned_lizard) although I'm not expert enough to identify the sub-species. This lizard is commonly called the horny toad, which is a pretty awkward name. Whoever thought this would be a good long-lasting brand name learned their lesson when [Horny Toad changed to Toad & Co](https://www.toadandco.com/blog/team-toad/horny-toad-becomes-toadco) back in 2015.